# Quicktime crashing after a few seconds

Tags: video, quicktime

I want to be able to watch the European Parliament on Ubuntu. I'm using Quicktime player, but it only works for a few seconds before crashing.

Here is a link to what I want to watch:
http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getVod.do?mode=chapter&language=EN&vodDateId=20140702-09:16:16-789

Comment: according to [this site](http://technologytales.com/2013/01/24/adding-quicktime-movie-support-to-firefox-running-on-linux/) you need to install `gecko-mediaplayer` on your computer

Answer (score 1):

The video in your link plays in VLC media player. To install VLC open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

1. Open Firefox, go to the video link, and under where it says APPLE QUICKTIME click on the link that says: *Select this  player*.
2. A QuickTime video player tab will open in Firefox. Inside the dark empty space in the video player click on the link that says: *Activate QuickTime*.
3. A popup window will appear asking if you will *Allow ... that video URL ... to run QuickTime?*. Click the *Allow Now* button.
4. Click the play button in the video player to start playing the video. It will start playing for a few seconds and then stop.
5. Right-click inside the video player and from the context menu select *Open with "VLC media player"*.
6. The video will open in VLC media player locally on your desktop, and start playing in VLC as a Network Stream. This particular video is more than two and a half hours long. It should play straight through in VLC media player from the beginning to the end without a break.